# Работа с кнопками на vue js

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите на примере, как добавить стиль к body при нажатии на кнопку.
Конкретная задача: при вызове модального окна скрыть убрать скролл у body. (чтобы не было двух скроллов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
methods: {
  onClickMethod() {
    document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    // дальше логика метода
  }
}
```

А на функции закрытия модального обратно возвращать боди оверфлоу: авто.